# Using $G_\delta$ version of measurability

Tags: measure-theory

If we consider: "$E$ is measurable if there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ such that $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(G\sim E)=0$" as our basic definition of measurability, I am trying to figure out how to prove that if $E,F$ are measurable then so is their union.

My train of thought:

$E$ measurable implies there is a $G_\delta$ set $G_1= \bigcap O_i $, where $O_i$ is open for each $i$, $E \subseteq G_1$, and $m^*(G_1 \sim E)=0$, and $F$ measurable implies there is a $G_\delta$ set $G_2= \bigcap V_i $, where $V_i$ is open for each $i$, $F \subseteq G_2$, and $m^*(G_2 \sim F)=0$. 
Then if we let $G= 
\bigcap (O_i \cup V_i)$, $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set, with $O_i \cup V_i$ open for each $i$, and $G$ contains $E \cup F$. Then $m^*(G \sim (E \cup F))=m^*((G \sim E) \cap (G \sim F))=m^*(G\sim E)+m^*(G \sim F)$. I know that I want to show $m^*(G \sim (E \cup F))=0$, but I am having trouble arriving at this step. I've tried writing it in terms of $G_1$ and $G_2$ but I keep getting stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying but if $m^*(G\setminus E)=0$ then $G\setminus E$ is measurable. And if $E$ and $F$ are measurable, then they belong to a $\sigma$-algebra,this implies that their union is measurable.

Comment: I've seen proof that the union of two measurable sets is measurable but I'm trying to prove it directly by using the $G_\delta$ fact above

Comment: I recommend isolating a part of solution into a lemma: the union of two $G_\delta$ sets is also $G_\delta$.

Comment: Sorry, its been a while since I've looked at this problem, but how did you find $m^{*}((G \setminus F) \cap (G \setminus E)) = m^{*}(G \setminus F) + m^*(G \setminus E)$?

Comment: I thought that was true but now I am doubting that fact. I can now show the union of two $G_\delta$ sets is $G_\delta$, and am now trying to use $G_1 \cup G_2$ as my $G_\delta$, but I still can't figure out how to manipulate it to get the result